# `mongoose-lean-getters` not working properly with `find` properly , calls the getter method twice

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using [**`lean`**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html), *(This makes queries faster and less memory intensive, but the result documents are plain old JavaScript objects (POJOs),)*

By default this will block all getters execution and provides POJO (plain old java object) so as a solution we can use [`mongoose-lean-getters`](https://plugins.mongoosejs.io/plugins/lean-getters) as per the **[standard doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html#plugins)**

**Schema :**

```
const mongooseLeanGetters = require('mongoose-lean-getters');
const rateSchema = new Schema({
    rate_photo: {
        type: String,
        get: getFullUrl
    }
);

rateSchema.plugin(mongooseLeanGetters);

const Rate = mongoose.model('rates', rateSchema);

module.exports = Rate;

function getFullUrl(url) {
    if (url != undefined) return `${process.env.ASSETS_URL}uploads/${url}`;
    else return '';
}
```

**Issue :**

```
model.Rate.find(condition).lean({ getters : true })
```

**Output:**

```
without getter :
"rate_photo": "rate/1574154457920-myw3schoolsimage.jpg",

With getter :
"rate_photo": "http://192.168.15.93:6600/assets/uploads/rate/1574154457920-myw3schoolsimage.jpg",

With lean:
"rate_photo": "rate/1574154457920-myw3schoolsimage.jpg",

With lean and findOne:
"rate_photo": "http://192.168.15.93:6600/assets/uploads/rate/1574154457920-myw3schoolsimage.jpg",

With lean and find: // <------------ ISSUE
expected result : 
    "rate_photo": "http://192.168.15.93:6600/assets/uploads/rate/1574154457920-myw3schoolsimage.jpg",
BUT GOT THIS :
    "rate_photo": "http://192.168.15.93:6600/assets/uploads/http://192.168.15.93:6600/assets/uploads/rate/1574154457920-myw3schoolsimage.jpg",
```

---

I have also found the **reason behind the issue**, in the npm package, they are calling getter twice via middleware **1st from `pre`** and **second from `post`** and this is only for `find` method alone :

```
module.exports = function mongooseLeanGetters(schema) {
  const fn = applyGettersMiddleware(schema);
  schema.pre('find', function() { //<--------------- 1st HERE
    if (typeof this.map === 'function') {
      this.map((res) => {
        fn.call(this, res);
        return res;
      });
    } else {
      this.options.transform = (res) => {
        fn.call(this, res);
        return res;
      };
    }
  });

  schema.post('find', fn); //<--------------- 2nd HERE
  schema.post('findOne', fn);
  schema.post('findOneAndUpdate', fn);
};
```

---

So If I comment out one of them ti works great, but the code is there for some reason, so Is there any better way to go ahead ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved in version : **[0.1.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-lean-getters)**

I think they have removed this to solve the issue :

```
schema.post('find', fn); //<--------------- 2nd HERE
```

Raised Issue on Github : https://github.com/mongoosejs/mongoose-lean-getters/issues/1